# How to deregister correctly from receiving notifications using IConnectPoint Unadvise?

Tags: c#, com, iconnectionpoint, mobile-broadband-api

In the [documentation for Mobile Broadband API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it says:

> The following procedure describes how to register for notifications.
>
> 1.Get an IConnectionPointContainer interface by calling QueryInterface on an IMbnInterfaceManager > object.
> 2.Call FindConnectionPoint on the returned interface and pass IID_IMbnPinEvents to riid.
> 3.Call Advise on the returned connection point and pass a pointer to an IUnknown interface on an > object that implements IMbnPinEvents to pUnk.
>
> Notifications can be terminated by calling Unadvise on the connection point returned in step 2.

I have got some code that carries out the first 3 steps, and it successfully registers for MBN events.
However, now I need to de-register temporarily from receiving these events.
So, after a couple of first attempts that ended with COM exceptions, I tried the following code (with try/catch blocks):

```
//First get the notifications

public void RegisterEvent(object iUnk, Guid guid, out uint storedTag)
{
IConnectionPoint icp = null;
Guid curGuid = guid;
storedTag = 0;
if ((curGuid == typeof(IMbnInterfaceManagerEvents).GUID) )              
{
  // For this event, the connection point is defined on the interface manager object
  m_InterfaceManagerCPC.FindConnectionPoint(ref curGuid, out icp);
  // Call Advise on the connection point to register
  icp.Advise(iUnk, out storedTag);
  //Save the IConnectionPoint object
  interfaceManagerCP = icp;

}

//Now deregister the events

public void DeregisterEvent(Guid guid, uint storedTag)
{
IConnectionPoint icp = null;
Guid curGuid = guid;

// Find the appropriate connection point to call Unadvise on
if ((curGuid == typeof(IMbnInterfaceManagerEvents).GUID) )              
{
  // Call Unadvise on the saved connection point to de-register
  interfaceManagerCP.Unadvise(storedTag);
}
```

When I run this code, I get no errors or exceptions from MBN.  But the event handlers aren't de-registered.  I can still see in the log files, MBN events arriving and being handled.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the problem.  I have many different types of GUIDs, and I thought they all used the same IConnectionPoint, so I saved it to the same object in the RegisterEvent function.

When I tried creating a new IConnectionPoint object for each GUID, and saving each IConnectionPoint separately, the DeregisterEvent function also worked properly.